# How to stop DB from creating multiple times in SQLite with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, swiftui

I have a DBHelper file which contains my SQLite functions to create, insert and select in a database. The database should only create once when a button is clicked, but as I go back and repress the button, a new database is created. Is there anyway to stop this from happening (like IF TABLE NOT EXISTS)? I need to store dummy data in the database, but this is not possible if a new database is created every time I try and save!

My DB Helper Class:

```
class DBHelper {
var db : OpaquePointer?
var path : String = "YOUFC.sqlite"
init() {
    self.db = createDB()
    self.createTable()       
}
```

My createDB Function:

```
func createDB() -> OpaquePointer? {
    let filePath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathExtension(path)

    var db : OpaquePointer? = nil
    
    if sqlite3_open(filePath.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("There is error in creating DB")
        return nil
    }else {
        print("Database has been created")
        return db
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you instantiating the DBHelper class and how does the button interact with it?

Comment: Hey, I use the DBHelper class in a button when a user finishes filling a form in, the button then saves these variables through the class.

Comment: Ok, without seeing more code, and going off your description, it seems like you're initializing the class once, and then initializing it again somewhere, which overwrites everything since createDB() is contained in the init function.  Is that the case, or do you for sure only initialize it once?

Comment: I definitely only initialise it once when the button is pressed, but the problem is if I press the button again a new Database is created - what I want to happen is that the data from the form is saved as a new record in the table in the same Database, not a new one. This would mean I wouldn’t be able to store multiple “users”

Comment: you can call createDB() as a method on button pressed instead of calling init()

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe your problem is that you're doing initial setup work of the database each time you initialize the DBHelper class (mainly the creating of the tables, not the DB itself), whereas you should ideally have that all setup ahead of time so that the DBHelper is just handling the select, insert and deletion queries.  If you prefer the app to create  the database for you when it first launches, you could use a UserDefaults key/value to check whether you successfully created the DB and table ahead of time, like so:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "databaseCreated") == false {
  createDBAndTables()
}

createDBAndTables() {
  //... create database and necessary tables
  // If the above code is successful, then set the following key
  UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "databaseCreated")
}
```

This way, you're just setting up the database once.  You can always add tables as needed in other events, but I would definitely try to get the main components setup first, and do it only once.